# How to trigger Express error middleware?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js, supertest

I'm trying to unit test this piece of code in Mocha:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.stack)
    res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
})
```

I don't know how to get my request inside a Mocha unit test to trigger it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First I would break out the middleware into its own file/function. As it sits, it's "integrated" with the Express app. So you're not testings *only* the error middleware, but also the Express app instance to an extent.

With that said, decouple the error middleware from the Express app:

`src/middleware/error-handler.js`

```
module.exports = (err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
}
```

You will still `.use()` it in the main `app.js` or wherever you setup Express:

```
const express = require('express')
const errorHandler = require('./src/middleware/error-handler')
const app = express()

app.use(errorHandler)
```

But now we're free of the Express dependency and we have a simple function we can isolate and test. Below is a simple test with [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) which you can easily adjust to work with Mocha.

`__tests__/middleware/error-handler.test.js`

```
const errorHandler = require('../../src/middleware')

describe('middleware.ErrorHandler', () => {
  /**
   * Mocked Express Request object.
   */
  let req

  /**
   * Mocked Express Response object.
   */
  let res

  /**
   * Mocked Express Next function.
   */
  const next = jest.fn()

  /**
   * Reset the `req` and `res` object before each test is ran.
   */
  beforeEach(() => {
    req = {
      params: {},
      body: {}
    }

    res = {
      data: null,
      code: null,
      status (status) {
        this.code = status
        return this
      },
      send (payload) {
        this.data = payload
      }
    }

    next.mockClear()
  })

  test('should handle error', () => {
    errorHandler(new Error(), req, res, next)

    expect(res.code).toBeDefined()
    expect(res.code).toBe(500)

    expect(res.data).toBeDefined()
    expect(res.data).toBe('Something broke!')
  })
})
```

Comment: TDD definitely facilitates braking modules out. And to keep unit tests fast and focused, this is preferred. However, supertest is great for doing some integration testing, e.g. you want to make sure an error correctly propagates through all your error handlers and gets logged. Is there a way to handle that with express and supertest? An API like `request(app).get('/some-route').throws(new Error)` that forces an error to be thrown from that route would be nice. It's a bit convoluted since your app may never actually end up throwing such an error, but at least it tests your error handlers.

Answer (score 0):

In your route you can pass an error object in the `next` parameter. For example:

```
app.get('/some-route', (req, res, next) => {
    const error = {....};

    next(error);
});
```

or just throw an error:

```
app.get('/some-route', (req, res, next) => {
    const error = {....};

    throw new Error(error);
});
```

Comment: Ideally, you wouldn't intentionally throw errors in your routes, and it may not be possible (or recommended?) to nicely add temporary routes during your test. Do you know if it's possible to use supertest to force an already defined route to throw an error?